# Concurrent HTTP POST Requests in Node?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, concurrency

I'd like to write load test case using Node, and the main part of is to perform 5000 requests simultaneously to an API using SOCKS5 proxy, and the second part is scanning each response and catching errors.

As I understand Node is a single threaded lang, but I could run multiple Node instances in same machine to take advantage of multi cores.

Still I'm not sure best way to implement this. I didn't even start to write the code as I'm not like to play with time. So, I'm looking to hear from community regarding possible implementation options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, networking in node.js is entirely non-blocking and asynchronous so sending 5000 requests and receiving 5000 requests is something that the single thread of node.js can do fairly efficiently.

If you have much CPU involved in processing the response, then you might benefit from involving some more CPUs.

Nodejs, now has [`WorkerThreads`](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) so the easiest way to involve multiple CPUs is to fire up N workerThreads (probably the same number as you have CPU cores in your system) and then give each workerThread a task to fire off N requests and report back results.  The WorkerThreads come with a message-based scheme for communicating with the main thread.

Depending upon how the test case works, you could either create a work queue in the main thread and then have each WorkerThread request a task whenever it's ready or if the work is simpler, you can just configure it so each WorkerThread runs N pre-designed requests when it starts up and reports when they are all done and what the results are.

In older versions of node.js, you could do the same thing with N child processes using the `child_process` module.

Comment: I'd like to know about the speed of requests. If I perform one by one, it would take approx an hour to complete. Obviously, I know nothing about inner-working of threads besides that it just works. In Jmeter for an example, If if fire up like 5000 threads at same time, it would complete blazing fast, but with one thread, it takes huge amount of time.

Comment: @sqlbie - It really depends upon what your code is doing so we could only really answer by seeing your code.  node.js can run 5000 network requests at once, in parallel. It can only process the results of the requests one at a time.  But, if most of the time is spent waiting for the remote server to respond and the processing of any individual request is pretty fast (a few ms), then 5000 requests could be pretty fast without using additional threads as nodejs is pretty efficient at that.

Comment: @sqlbie - On, the other hand, if processing a given response in your Javascript takes 5 seconds of CPU time, then it will take 5000*5 seconds to process them all if you have just one thread.  So, it really depends upon your code and what you're doing.   You can either shows us your code to get more advice or run your own test.

Comment: "It can only process the results of the requests one at a time", maybe this is my exact question. How to speed up the result processing time? What's the best implementation method in Node for that? 

Response length is about 300 chars. Certainly, I will run my own test and get back to you if I have any questions, but in mean time it would be great if you can answer that one so I can be confident that I'm on the right track.

Comment: @sqlbie -  A 300 byte response is nothing.  I  suspect you're making a big problem out of nothing.  Just test running 5000 requests in a single thread and see how ti performs and if you want further help after that, then share the exact test results and show us your code for the test.

Comment: "you're making a big problem out of nothing" - This is essentially true, I always known Node indeed had big problem at threading, because when I was non-technical user, I outsourced some project to Asian based programmer, he had lot of difficulties making it work as it took lot of time to process requests so he ended up using Python instead.

Comment: @sqlbie - All I know is that one of node.js strengths is doing lots of asynchronous I/O.  I'm not saying that you won't be able to go a bit faster with some threads, but I am saying that there's no reason to design a threaded solution until you've tested the non-threaded solution and proved you actually have an issue worth solving.  My favorite saying related to this is that "a design should be no more complicated than necessary to solve the problem".  Unnecessary complication is a bad design and typically takes a lot longer to code, test and make reliable.

Comment: I can confirm Node is working perfectly for this. It made 1000 requests thru Socks5 proxy in 5 min.  I used Bluebird .all method to construct all requests and perform all at same time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, Would I able to scan response at same time as request made so that I can cancel other request if error caught? Right now, I have to do this later after all requests made. So I thought this may need threading.

Comment: @sqlbie - Sorry, I don't understand what that last comment means.  Unless you are specifically coding with Worker Threads, Node.js runs your JS in a single thread so no two pieces of Javascript are ever running at the exact same time.  Asynchronous I/O lets the I/O happen in the background, but not the processing of the response.  That happens in the foreground in the single thread.

Comment: That explains it. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know if you could help me. I've discovered an issue where the system hangs at random times. Eg: after making 4000 requests then halt rest requests then wait indefinitely without doing anything. Most of times it work fine. I always have to restart whole program to fix it.

Comment: I was able to fix it by limiting concurrency to 20. I guess previous issue seems related with OS level or Proxy level.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm Node is working perfectly for this. It made 1000 requests thru a proxy in 5 min.  I used Bluebird .all method to construct all requests and perform all at same time.

While Node is single threaded, Networking is multi threaded. I think that's why it's so fast.